# Kafka Connector - why is consumer creating a topic even though connector is not existing?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Im confused at this subject. One of my services has a consumer which listens on a topic. Im checking the topics in CMAK. If my consumer is up and running and if I delete the topic in CMAK it instantly creates the same one or doesnt delete at all.

Here's what I do;
I delete the connector via Postman, I send a delete request. Then I confirm that the connector is deleted by get request. Then I stop my service. And then I delete the topic. And then I make some changes in database whom my consumer is listening for. I create a document and make some updates on it. Then when I start my service it instantly gets all the updates. And I checked if the connector is opened as well but nope. There is no connector yet there is a topic. And I want to know why is this happening.

Its a problem because I wrote a bash script which listens for the service whom my consumer is listening. And when that service is healthy my script triggers a curl request to open a connector. And so my consumer starts listening, hence automating the Kafka connection. If my service is automatically creates a topic then what need is there for my script?

TLDR: Why does a consumer creates a topic without connector?

I hope its clear.

Comment: Does your broker have auto topic creation enabled? Is there a producer actively running? Did you know there's a Connect worker config to auto create topics as well?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Sorry for the late reply. It says in the docs that broker configuration enables topic creation at runtime by default. And this explains why the topic is being created when my consumer service started.

Comment: The broker setting is for producers, however, not consumers. When consumers start for non-existing topics, they start printing `UnknownTopicOrPartition`. If you stop Debezium connector, there should be no producer, therefore no topic automatically created (assuming the setting is enabled on the broker, which is not recommended)